# Crash issue in OnResume

Tags: android

If application stay in background mode more then 5 min. after that i try to open Application at that time got crash issue my Error log is here help me thanks in Advance....

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity` ComponentInfo{com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid/com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.TabbedActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid/com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.EarnCoinActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid/com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.EarnCoinActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2043)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
at com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.TabbedActivity.addTab(TabbedActivity.java:199)
at com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.TabbedActivity.setTabs(TabbedActivity.java:180)
at com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.TabbedActivity.onCreate(TabbedActivity.java:140)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.EarnCoinActivity.onCreate(EarnCoinActivity.java:110)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
... 23 more
```

Comment: can you post some of your code Thanks.

Comment: what is code at line 110 in EarnCoinActivity ?

Comment: i got same issue in my All Activity class so this is common crash issue i also check my all class code and i got crash issue if my app was stay in background mode more then 5 min. please help me if you khow solution becasuse my app is live in play store...

Comment: Haresh Chhelana  this is class name which having crash issue in onresume(); after comeback 5 min.

Comment: post onCreate() method from EarnCoinActivity and mark line : 110

Answer (score 1):

While your application stayed in the background it got killed by the system. Somewhere in com.gamestruct.TweetBoostAndroid.EarnCoinActivity.onCreate (presumably on line 110) you are using something that became null as your app was killed.

Comment: but have same issue in my Application All classes.

Comment: Yes, because your app got killed and you probably have some singleton or something which you are trying to access but it became null. Make sure you initialize it if it's null

Comment: 110 line having instance of interface class.

Comment: Where do you initialize that instance? You probably initialize it somewhere else. So, your Activity starts and it has null because nthing else yet happened

Comment: same line. like this RefreshUserClass userClass = new RefreshUserClass(EarnCoinActivity.this);

Comment: One thing you can do to make debugging eaiser: go to Settings|Developer Options and check 'Do not save Activities' checkbox. This way you won't have to wait 5 min, it'll immediately crash when you resume your app from the background

Comment: i follow that steps and try but app doesn't crash.